# How to remove header when use angular httpClient to post a text?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

When I send a text using angular httpclient, the server always receive the header information with the text. My code is similar to this:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
...
constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}
...
body = "abcdefgkek"
this.http.post(this.url, body);
```

Server receives data (convert from hex to text) as:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:3001
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 91
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; MHA-L09 Build/HUAWEIMHA-L09; wv) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/75.0.3770.143 
Mobile Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain
X-Requested-With: io.ionic.starter
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-AU,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8

abcdefgkek
```

How can I only send the text, then the server only gets the data as:

```
abcdefgkek
```

Comment: its the request header which is inserted by your browser, you can get the data from the request body , which will only contain `abcdefgkek`

Comment: Why would you drop the whole header? You can send the data in body or define your own header with some key/value pair to send that data.

Comment: `Content-Type:text/plain `